# Can a single point be considered (the image of) a curve?

Tags: curves

I know that a curve is a continuous function from the unit interval to $\mathbb{R}^n$. That raises the question, can a single point be considered the image of a curve?

Comment: The constant function has the single point on which every number is mapped as the complete image. Hence, the answer is "yes".

Comment: Take also into account that the word "curve" is reused to name multiple concepts. When distinction is needed, some people call the concept that you defined "parametric curve".